# Nested object from HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, object

I have this structure object :

```
let obj = {
  hello: {
    the: {
      world: {
        very: 'cool'
      }
    },
    other: 'universe'
  },
  bye: 'bye'
}
```

i generated an html for this where i can edit both key and values :

```
<div id="object">
<input name="hello" id="hello" class="block nested" type="text" value="hello">
<div id="object">
    <input name="the" id="the" class="block nested" type="text" value="the">
    <div id="object">
        <input name="world" id="world" class="block nested" type="text" value="world">
        <div id="pair">
            <input name="very" id="very" type="text" value="very">
            <input id="cool" type="text" value="cool">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="pair">
    <input name="other" id="other" type="text" value="other">
    <input id="universe" type="text" value="universe">
</div>
```

I try to modify each input, and re generated same object structure with updated key and values.

I tried this :

```
let objUpdated = {};
let subObject = {};
const loopIntoNodes = (nodeArray) => {
  Array.from(nodeArray).forEach((subNode) => {
      if (subNode.id === 'object') {
        subObject = {[subNode.firstChild.name]: {}}
        objUpdated = {...objUpdated, ...subObject};
        loopIntoNodes(subNode.firstChild.nextSibling.childNodes);
      }
      else if (subNode.id === 'pair') {
        objUpdated = {...objUpdated, ...{[subNode.firstChild.name]:subNode.firstChild.nextSibling.value}};
      }
  });
  console.log(objUpdated);
}

  const body = document.querySelector('body div');
  loopIntoNodes(body.childNodes);
```

But i can't find the logic to correctly reassemble my nested object from the html.
I known when i have an input then a id object div, next value must be the key from the next div, and if i have a div pair id, it must be a key and value.

Comment: Your html is invalid, `id` must be unique.

Comment: yes you are right. I'll fix it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you should change id with something else, you could use `data` attributes for example. Then you could create recursive function that will take one root element and then based on `div` and `inputs` that are inside build the nested structure.

```js
const element = document.querySelector('body > div');

function toObject(element, result = {}) {
  const divs = element.querySelectorAll(':scope > div');
  const inputs = element.querySelectorAll(':scope > input');
  const [key, value] = [...inputs].map(e => e.dataset.id);

  if (element.dataset.id == 'pair') {
    result[key] = value
  }

  divs.forEach(div => {
    const id = div.dataset.id;

    if (!result[key]) {
      result[key] = {}
    }

    toObject(div, result[key])
  })

  return result;
}

const result = toObject(element);
console.log(result)
```

```html
<div data-id="object">
  <input name="hello" data-id="hello" class="block nested" type="text" value="hello">

  <div data-id="object">
    <input name="the" data-id="the" class="block nested" type="text" value="the">
    <div data-id="object">
      <input name="world" data-id="world" class="block nested" type="text" value="world">
      <div data-id="pair">
        <input name="very" data-id="very" type="text" value="very">
        <input data-id="cool" type="text" value="cool">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div data-id="pair">
    <input name="other" data-id="other" type="text" value="other">
    <input data-id="universe" type="text" value="universe">
  </div>
</div>
```